# Using sed , awk to extract lines of data between a pattern till the beginning of a line with a special character

Tags: sed, awk, grep

i have the following xml

```
## 13 Aug 2013 14:53:44, 390 [INFO] OrderId 100 otherInfo
<someXML>details
<info>details<info>
<info1>details<info1>
</someXML>
## 13 Aug 2013 14:53:44, 390 [INFO] OrderId 105 otherInfo
<someXML>details
<info>details<info>
<info1>details<info1>
</someXML>
## 13 Aug 2013 14:55:45, 490 [INFO] OrderId 100 otherInfo  
<someXML>details
<info>details<info>
<info1>details<info1>
</someXML>
## 13 Aug 2013 14:53:44, 390 [INFO] OrderId 105 otherInfo
<someXML>details
<info>details<info>
<info1>details<info1>
</someXML>
```

i want to search for a particular line with orderid "example OrderId 100" and print both that line and everything below it till the next order line starting with doulbe hash(##)
so if i search with orderid 100 i should get the following

```
## 13 Aug 2013 14:53:44, 390 [INFO] OrderId 100 otherInfo
<someXML>details
<info>details<info>
<info1>details<info1>
</someXML>
## 13 Aug 2013 14:55:45, 490 [INFO] OrderId 100 otherInfo 
<someXML>details
<info>details<info>
<info1>details<info1>
</someXML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your records are nicely separated so set the record separator to `##` and search for the `OrderId` you want:

```
$ awk '/OrderId 100/{print RS $0}' RS='##' ORS=''  file
## 13 Aug 2013 14:53:44, 390 [INFO] OrderId 100 otherInfo
<someXML>details
<info>details<info>
<info1>details<info1>
</someXML>
## 13 Aug 2013 14:55:45, 490 [INFO] OrderId 100 otherInfo
<someXML>details
<info>details<info>
<info1>details<info1>
</someXML>
```

Comment: Just worth mentioning that setting RS to more than one character makes this GNU awk specific.

Comment: Thnks a lot..really helpful....   is there any way i can use the awk command to extract the orderid based on a FROM dateTime and ToDateTime? given the datetime is given in the format in the sample?

Comment: You would just replace the regex string `/OrderId 100/` to the regex you want to match. If this answer solves your problem then you should accept it by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/OrderId 100/!d;:a;$!{n;/^##/{s/^/\n/;D};ba}' file
```